# restTemplate call where the parameter to the function is MultipartHttpServletRequest request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hi I have to make a resttemplate call to make to following function where the Params are MultiPartHttpServletRequest request,HttpServletRequest requestForm, HttpServletResponse response

```
Map<String, String> upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
                                       HttpServletRequest requestForm, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("name") String name,
                                       @RequestParam("id") String id,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "contanctno", required = false, defaultValue = Constants.DIGITS) String contactNo,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "address", required = false,) String address) throws InvalidReqException
```

Along with that the problem is that I have the file which is to be sent but how to send that particular file along with name version.pdf where version always changes .Can someone help me with it

Request Method = POST

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to save the new file with the new name on hard disk, you can add the `MultipartFile` as parameter and copy the file contents from the uploaded file to a new file on your disk:

```java
Map<String, String> upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletRequest requestForm, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("id") String id,
    @RequestParam(value = "contanctno", required = false, defaultValue = Constants.DIGITS) String contactNo,
    @RequestParam(value = "address", required = false) String address,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws InvalidReqException {

    String newFileName = "newFileName.pdf";
    File newPdf = new File(newFileName);
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), newPdf.toPath());

    // more code...
}
```

Comment: No I cant do this because  api which is already there.I just have to make a wrapper around it which makes call to this api using restTemplate

Comment: Can you describe the other API you're talking about? Are you using `upload()` in the post to make request to another API?

Comment: This is the api for which I have to make a restTemplate call

Comment: I have file that is to be sent in my local but how to make restTemplate call ?

Comment: Both are in different projects so using a restTemplate I can use that api functionality

Comment: The provided information on the question is too little to give an answer to. You have two projects, one in spring boot and the other in what?

Comment: the other project using Spring MVC

Comment: You can use the library `HttpClient` to make a REST call from the other project: https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client